# Django Comments and Rating Systems

Tags: django, comments, blogs, rating

I am looking for a blogging and comments system that can smoothly integrate with my Django sites. I've found there is a lot on the Net and got lost a bit, and I don't have much experience on this. Hope you guys can give me some suggestions.

Here are the things that I would like to have:

- Tag Clouds
- Articles Archive (by months/by years)
- Articles Rating (e.g. with Stars or customize icons)
- Comments to the particular Topic/Articles
- Sub-Comments of a particular comments (i.e. following up comments)
- Blogs/Articles Searching
- Able to relate other articles that is relevant (i.e. follow up Articles)
- Pagination of the comments if get too long
- OpenIDs supports (e.g. facebook, hotmail, blogger, twitter...etc)
- Support login before user can comments
- Able to retrieve Blogs' Header and customized the display order
- Able to subscribe this article to RSS
- Able to Email this to friends (this may not belongs to the comments system)

If I missed some common functions, please let me know. The comments system I am looking for should do most jobs that those popular comments system should do on the web, e.g. WordPress.

Thank you so much everyone. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

I myself really like [django-threadedcomments](http://github.com/ericflo/django-threadedcomments). It supports threaded commenting like what you would see in [Disqus](http://disqus.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @jpartogi, the Disqus site is pretty! But why people don't use the Django’s built in comments framework? Is there any limitation there?

Comment: My experience is django's built in commenting framework is very basic and most of all it is suck at spam prevention.

Comment: It might also come to your interest that disqus is made with django.

Answer (score 0):

i heard [django-comment-utils](http://code.google.com/p/django-comment-utils/) is quite good. - may you test it :)