# Comment and Rating system for Django

Tags: django, django-comments, rating-system

I am new to Django, I don't know a lot of them.

I am trying to build a comment and rating system for a blog in Django. There are some apps that I can use to achieve this(Comment and Rating)?

Please let me know.

Best Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752967/django-comments-and-rating-systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `django.contrib.comments` that comes with django works well, even if it is rather simplistic.  Seems to be extendable for more elaborate needs, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Django-ThreadedComents(http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-threadedcomments) is an alternative to Django Comments? Django-ThreadedComents have moderation like Django Comments?

Comment: I haven't looked at django-threadedcomments, but it seems to be an extension of django.contrib.comments, so I assume it has at least the same (basic) support for moderation as django.contrib.comments has.

Answer (score 1):

At Eldarion, we've ended up building and using **dialogos** for all our comments on sites: https://github.com/eldarion/dialogos

And for ratings are extending **agon**: https://github.com/eldarion/agon

While **agon** was originally just about giving people points, it can also be used to give arbitrary objects points and this can be used for both voting and rating.

Both of these apps will have extensive use in the next release of **Pinax**.